# mongo db query binary data sorted by size

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have some binary data inside a mongodb collection. I would like to clear a little bit the too heavy data. How can I sort the top 10 binary data (biggest size on disk)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { binSize: { $bsonSize: "$binary_data" } } },
  { $sort: { binSize: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 }
])
```